# Setting up socket communication with ktor

Tags: kotlin, sockets, intellij-idea, ktor

Recently, I was given a task, where I have to open a socket communication over tcp channel using ktor. The connection should be to a given endpoint and port. I am also given a certificate, that I've put in resources. called cert.jks, that should be provided, probably to SSLContext. I should be able to read and write to the channel

Although ktor has good docs, I cannot for the love of me set this thing up. Any help would be appreciated

Here is the relevant doc
https://ktor.io/docs/servers-raw-sockets.html

Comment: If this is for a client, then see https://ktor.io/docs/servers-raw-sockets.html#secure